# How can I an add array of values to a key programatically?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am new in Ruby and I wanna add a block of hash to the top of the programmer_hash:

```
def adding_matz
    programmer_hash = 
    {
    :grace_hopper => {
      :known_for => "COBOL",
      :languages => ["COBOL", "FORTRAN"]
    },
    :alan_kay => {
      :known_for => "Object Orientation",
      :languages => ["Smalltalk", "LISP"]
    },
    :dennis_ritchie => {
      :known_for => "Unix",
      :languages => ["C"]
    }
 }
end
```

This is what I want to add to the top of `programmer_hash` hash:

```
:yukihiro_matsumoto => {
    :known_for => "Ruby",
     :languages => ["LISP", "C"]
}
```

I have added the code below at the end of the method:

```
programmer_hash[:yukihiro_matsumoto] = [:known_for['Ruby']]
programmer_hash[:yukihiro_matsumoto][:languages] = 'LISP'
programmer_hash[:yukihiro_matsumoto][:languages] = 'C'
```

It worked pretty well, but I want to do all of this in one line, but nothing comes out right. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: _"I have added the code below [...] It worked pretty well"_ – I doubt so. `:known_for['Ruby']` returns `nil`, so the first line would assign `[nil]` to the key `:yukihiro_matsumoto`. The second line would then result in an error.

Answer (score 2):

Assign a new hash to `:yukihiro_matsumoto` key in the main hash:

```
programmer_hash[:yukihiro_matsumoto] = { 
  known_for: 'Ruby'
  languages: ['LISP', 'C']
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge two hashes. Standard docs for [merge!](https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/merge!)

```
programmer_hash = {
    :grace_hopper => {
        :known_for => "COBOL",
        :languages => ["COBOL", "FORTRAN"]
     },
    :alan_kay => {
        :known_for => "Object Orientation",
        :languages => ["Smalltalk", "LISP"]
     },
    :dennis_ritchie => {
        :known_for => "Unix",
        :languages => ["C"]
    }
}
```

Then you have your another hash like below

```
another_hash = { 
    :yukihiro_matsumoto => {
        :known_for => "Ruby",
         :languages => ["LISP", "C"]
    }
}
```

Then you can merge them by -

```
programmer_hash.merge!(another_hash)
```